# Proof about self-adjoint linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex inner product space. Prove that given any self-adjoint linear transformation $f:V\rightarrow V$ there exists a self-adjoint linear transformation $g:V\rightarrow V$ such that $f=g^5$.

I'm not sure how to even begin so I would appreciate some guidance if it's not too much to ask. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Start by diagonalizing the linear transformation. Then it should be clear how $g$ should look like. You need only to prove that $g$ is still self-adjoint.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit lost :( would you mind elaborating a little bit? How do I diagonalise the linear transformation?

Comment: Do you know of the "spectral theorem"?

Comment: I certainly have been exposed to it, but I can't say I know how to utilise it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We need to use the spectral theorem.  In particular, we know that there exists a *diagonal* transformation and unitary $u$ such that $d_f:V \to V$ such that $f = u \; d_f \; u^*$.

Start by finding a diagonal $d_g$ such that $d_g^5 = d_f$.  Then, it suffices to note that 
$$
[u \;d_g\;u^* ]^5 = u \; d_g^5 \; u^* = f
$$

Comment: To find $d_g^5$, we would just take the fifth root of the entries of $d_f$?

Comment: To find $d_g$, we would just take the fifth roots. There is no need to "find" $d_g^5$.